# How to get local display via ssh?

Tags: python, selenium, ssh

I'm trying to do some stuff when I get/leave home via 'Run script via SSH' in Apple Shortcuts. 
I wrote some python script in local machine (Windows 10) and trying to run it via SSH.
I also tested without Apple Shortcuts. I mean, just access to Windows 10 via SSH from my MacBook and tested, so it's not a problem with Apple Shortcuts.

What I want

- I want to run python scripts in my Windows 10 Desktop, via SSH (Run script via SSH option from iPhone)
- I want to open browser via selenium and make it do so some stuffs from me
- I want my python script also turn on and turn off the monitor

Here's the problem.

- It seems when I access to OpenSSH server via SSH, python script cannot recognize the local display
- When I make a selenium instance, no problem with python but doesn't pop up in desktop monitor
- It definately works when I run jupyter in Windows 10 and run the same script
- Also, python script from local jupyter server is able to turn on/off the monitor, but from SSH it can't

What's the problem? How can I solve it? Any clue would help me a lot

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. You're sitting in front of a mac? And you want to run programs on a Windows system through ssh? Which display do you want these programs to access, mac or windows? Are you running an X server on either system? Or using VNC, or some other screen sharing?

Comment: OpenSSH server is running on Windows 10. I want to open browser in there, turn on/off the monitor in there. I use iPhon/mac to login to the ssh server!